# Starting learning Angular/Node issues when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I’m trying to configure a simple Angular / NodeJS app and deploy it with heroku.  I'm new on the Angular/Node world, I'm following an online course, locally all works great but when deploying I cannot execute it.

I get the following error when I try to execute on the browser:
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "ggrande",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod",
    "start": "node server.js"
    },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.0-beta4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.0.0",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

My Profile is simply:

```
web: node server.js
```

And the server.json is:

```
    var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
const path = require('path');

var USERS_COLLECTION = "users";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));



// Create a database variable outside of the database connection callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;

// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function (err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
  db = client.db();
  console.log("Database connection ready");

  // Initialize the app.
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });

  app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(distDir + '/myapp/index.html'));
  })
});
```

EDIT: I resolved the crash, the problem was in the server.js file. But now /dist/index.html returns a blank page...how it could be?

Thanks in advance for a help.

Comment: might u will get ur solution, follow the link - https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/1589

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with heroku, but i resolved it by getting the logs files.

Just do one thing, see your logs, you will get the exact error.

*1) Go to your project directories, 
2) open terminal/cmd
3) type "heroku logs -n 500" command.*

it will shows you all the activity of your heroku app, then find the red marked texts, you will get to know the exact errors.

if you can't resolve the issue, just post a clear screenshot of your logs.

Thanks

Comment: The error log is: 2018-05-24T09:36:58.926338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=testApp.herokuapp.com request_id=a3fb7146-0807-45e0-954d-23b2f19f1f98 fwd="188.218.155.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https